# Sbt upgrade error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Interceptor

Tags: sbt

I have an issue when trying to upgrade current sbt version (`1.6.2`). I tried both `1.8.3` and `1.9.3`

The error output below was obtained from the `1.9.3` attempt:

```bash
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/Interceptor
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:24)
at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:32)
at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1(ModuleUtilities.scala:37)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.$anonfun$map$1(Stream.scala:418)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1173)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1163)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.loop$1(Growable.scala:57)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:61)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:184)
at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.to(TraversableLike.scala:786)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.to$(TraversableLike.scala:783)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:350)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toList$(TraversableOnce.scala:350)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toList(Traversable.scala:108)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.$plus$plus(List.scala:216)
at sbt.internal.PluginDiscovery$.discoverAll(PluginDiscovery.scala:59)
at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:1330)
at sbt.internal.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:1275)
at sbt.internal.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:1254)
at sbt.internal.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:1233)
at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$2(Load.scala:701)
at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1407)
at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:701)
at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1407)
at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:695)
at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:493)
at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:181)
at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:246)
at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:555)
at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:571)
at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:501)
at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:480)
at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:242)
at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1407)
at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:242)
at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:57)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:964)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:964)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:917)
at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:151)
at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:146)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:190)
at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$processCommand$5(MainLoop.scala:246)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at sbt.MainLoop$.process$1(MainLoop.scala:246)
at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:279)
at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$5(MainLoop.scala:164)
at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.runCmd$1(State.scala:290)
at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.process$extension(State.scala:326)
at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$4(MainLoop.scala:164)
at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:24)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:164)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:145)
at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:120)
at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:28)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:113)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:67)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:52)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:43)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:225)
at sbt.xMain$.$anonfun$run$11(Main.scala:135)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at scala.Console$.withIn(Console.scala:230)
at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withIn(Terminal.scala:610)
at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.$anonfun$withStreams$1(Terminal.scala:390)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:167)
at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.$anonfun$withOut$2(Terminal.scala:600)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
at scala.Console$.withErr(Console.scala:196)
at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withOut(Terminal.scala:600)
at sbt.internal.util.Terminal$.withStreams(Terminal.scala:390)
at sbt.xMain$.withStreams$1(Main.scala:88)
at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:123)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.java:59)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:47)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$run$1(Launch.scala:149)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:176)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:149)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.$anonfun$apply$1(Launch.scala:44)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:159)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:44)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:21)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:78)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.run(Boot.scala:73)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.Interceptor
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 96 more
```

JDK version: 11.0.19-tem (from SDKMAN)
I used the sbt shell of IntelliJ (2023.1.2 UE Build #IU-231.9011.34)

The beginning of loading the project confirms the sbt and JDK version:

```bash
$USER_HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.19-tem/bin/java -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xss256m -Didea.managed=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Didea.installation.dir=$USER_HOME/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/231.9011.34/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents -jar $USER_HOME/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/231.9011.34/IntelliJ IDEA.app.plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar
[info] welcome to sbt 1.9.3 (Eclipse Adoptium Java 11.0.19)
```

Another observation is that the internal file that leads to reflection error (`ModuleUtilities.scala` from `zinc-classpath`) is of version 2.12-1.6.0 according to IntelliJ's Project view, but looking [at MVNRepo it should align](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/zinc-classpath) with the sbt version. That could be more a symptom of failing to upgrade:

[image]

**UPDATE** Unfortunately I get the same output when doing `sbt --version` from the repository root using CLI:

```bash
➜  sbt --version
// same error output as above
sbt script version: 1.9.3
```

I can see `okhttp3.Interceptor` in `okhttp-3.14.2.jar` under `sbt-1.9.3` in IntelliJ's library section of the Project view, but it would seem that `okhttp` should have been [removed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/c04b2a4f732de848fec564b8c4ec694a156d11c8) since version `1.7.0`.

I am also not seeing an `okhttp3` dependency in 1.9.3 version of sbt using Coursier:

```
➜  1.0 cs resolve -t org.scala-sbt:sbt:1.9.3 | grep okhttp
  Result:
```

JIC, our resolvers:

```scala
resolvers ++= Resolver.sonatypeOssRepos("releases")
```

**Update** also have this

```scala
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      "Typesafe Repo" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
      "osgeo" at "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/"
    )
```

`build.properties` file:

```
sbt.version=1.9.3
```

FWIW this same error happens as part of the CD pipeline (gitlab). These are the images that we are using for Gitlab runners (we use 1.8.2 there):

```
  SBT_IMAGE_11: sbtscala/scala-sbt:eclipse-temurin-11.0.17_8_1.8.2_2.13.10
  SBT_IMAGE_8: sbtscala/scala-sbt:eclipse-temurin-8u352-b08_1.8.2_2.13.10
```

The intended sbt version is downloaded there too:

```
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.9.3  (this may take some time)...
[info] [launcher] getting Scala 2.12.18 (for sbt)...
[info] welcome to sbt 1.9.3 (Red Hat, Inc. Java 1.8.0_342)
```

I'd appreciate any help in direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystery got solved. The culprit was the `"com.gilcloud" % "sbt-gitlab" % "0.0.6"` dependency that we for artifact publishing to a Maven repository.

Upgrading that plugin to version `0.1.2` fixed the issue. Well almost..:

if you have a [sbt multi-project build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html) (like we do) please note that, in addition to bumping-up the version, you will have to move gitlab settings to every sub project, e.g.

```scala
// in build.sbt
lazy val gitlabSettings = Seq(
  ...
  GitlabPlugin.autoImport.gitlabDomain := "gitlab.com",
  GitlabPlugin.autoImport.gitlabProjectId := ...
  GitlabPlugin.autoImport.gitlabCredentials := ...
)

lazy val module1 = (project in file("module1"))
  .settings(
    name := "module1",
    sharedSettings
  )
```

It maybe interesting from historical perspective how did I get to finding the culprit:

I first added the artifact for the missing class definition to `project/plugins.sbt` (you won't need it after upgrading sbt-gitlab plugin):

```scala
// in project/plugins.sbt
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.squareup.okhttp3" % "okhttp" % "4.11.0")
```

This is when the sbt error became more indicative - it started complaining about missing `sbt.internal.CustomHTTP` dependency for a class in a `com.gilcloud` package. That drove me to the plugin's release pages where I found a note about their [fix for sbt 1.7.0+ versions](https://github.com/gilcloud/sbt-gitlab/releases/tag/v0.1.2).